# how to run two instances of an android application on a device

Tags: android

I want to write an app helper for producing a new instance of any other applications ,even though the old instance still running on device.
In fact,this app should be like Parallel Space of LBE. I gather some information about the theory,such as changing the tag app's uid after launching the first instance,and then running the second instance on a new dalvik vm,but i don't know how to enter on it.
Any suggestion to give me,this is my first question after signing up？

Comment: I interesting too. Although I think u need in root access